# Fit a page to table

Tags: tables, longtable, paper-size

How can I fit a page to show an entire table (all I've seen here is the opposed, fit the table size to the page size. But, as I'll not print the result, I want to do the opposite)

This is a sample of my table (I need use `longtable` because it uses 2 pages)

```
\documentclass[landscape, letter]{report}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=0cm,top=.5cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\title{titulo}
\author{Rodrigo Coster - 1141783-01}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\textbf{{\LARGE Relação de vagas autorizadas, providas e disponíveis}}\end{center}
\tiny
\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\hline
\multirow{3}*{Cod.} & \multirow{3}*{Sec.} & \multicolumn{12}{c}{Categoria A} & \multicolumn{12}{c}{Categoria B} & \multicolumn{12}{c}{Categoria G} \\ 
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{4h}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{5h}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{6h}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Total} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{4h}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{5h}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{6h}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Total} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{4h}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{5h}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{6h}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Total} \\
& & A & P & D & A & P & D & A & P & D & A & P & D & A & P & D & A & P & D & A & P & D & A & P & D & A & P & D & A & P & D & A & P & D & A & P & D \\ 
\rowcolor{yellow} 187 & GP & \cellcolor{red} 5 & \cellcolor{red} 6 & \cellcolor{red} -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 5 & \cellcolor{red} 6 & \cellcolor{red} -1 &  6 &  4 &  2 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  23 &  20 &  3 &  29 &  25 &  4 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
\rowcolor{yellow} 912 & SMA &  46 &  35 &  11 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  24 &  15 &  9 &  70 &  50 &  20 &  10 &  8 &  2 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  26 &  10 &  16 &  36 &  22 &  14 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 6 & \cellcolor{red} -6 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 6 & \cellcolor{red} -6 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 12 & \cellcolor{red} -12 \\
 825 & SMACIS &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
\rowcolor{yellow} 925 & SMACIS & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{red} -2 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{red} -2 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{red} -2 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{red} -2 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
\rowcolor{yellow} 83 & SMED &  151 &  8 &  143 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  151 &  8 &  143 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{red} -2 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 1 & \cellcolor{red} -1 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 3 & \cellcolor{red} -3 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 37 & \cellcolor{red} -37 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 6 & \cellcolor{red} -6 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 44 & \cellcolor{red} -44 \\
\rowcolor{yellow} 913 & SMF & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 73 & \cellcolor{red} -73 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 73 & \cellcolor{red} -73 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 35 & \cellcolor{red} -35 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 37 & \cellcolor{red} -37 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 73 & \cellcolor{red} -73 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 10 & \cellcolor{red} -10 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 5 & \cellcolor{red} -5 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 15 & \cellcolor{red} -15 \\
\rowcolor{yellow} 7 & SMED &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  67 &  0 &  67 &  67 &  0 &  67 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 8 & \cellcolor{red} -8 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  124 &  63 &  61 &  124 &  71 &  53 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 10 & \cellcolor{red} -10 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 51 & \cellcolor{red} -51 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 61 & \cellcolor{red} -61 \\
\rowcolor{yellow} 918 & SMS &  138 &  93 &  45 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{red} 3 & \cellcolor{red} -1 &  140 &  97 &  43 &  93 &  43 &  50 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  13 &  2 &  11 &  106 &  47 &  59 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 17 & \cellcolor{red} -17 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 1 & \cellcolor{red} -1 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 19 & \cellcolor{red} -19 \\
\rowcolor{yellow} 166 & SMS &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{red} 5 & \cellcolor{red} -3 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{red} 5 & \cellcolor{red} -3 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  103 &  52 &  51 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  103 &  54 &  49 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{red} -2 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cellcolor{red} 0 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{red} -2 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, after using `\tiny`, one column is still missing.

Comment: Do you need it to be tight to the table, or simply make it wider, putting `\advance\pdfpagewidth1in` just before `\begin{longtable}` works for example, or do you want to measure the table?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need it to be tight to the table, or simply make it wider, putting

```
\addtolength\pdfpagewidth{1in}
```

just before `\begin{longtable}` works for example. It would be possible to measure the table exactly on a later run. but usually it is sufficient to just increase by a fixed amount.

Note that `\pdfpagewidth` just affects the size the pdf viewer uses to clip the view, the table will still be `overfull` for TeX, if you want to change that then you might also want

\addtolength\textwidth{1in}

in the preamble of the document.

Of course it doesn't have to be `1in` any TeX length will work.